Extend contex.store object in Elysia.JS to sotre requestId
I am implementing logger plugin to automatically logging per request, response
I need to share requestId so I tried to extend ctx.store object:
import { generateRequestID, getLogger } from "@G-day-travel/common";
import { Elysia } from "elysia";
import { Context } from "elysia/dist/context";
import { StatusMap } from "elysia";

export const logger = getLogger({
  moduleName: "trinity-was",
  mode: process.env.NODE_ENV,
});

export const loggerPlugin = (app: Elysia) => {

  return app
    .resolve((ctx: Context) => ({
      store: {
        requestId: generateRequestID(),
        start: Date.now(),
      },
    }))
    .onBeforeHandle((ctx: Context) => {
      const {requestId} = ctx.store; //error
      const { method, url } = ctx.request; 

      logger.requestLog({method, url, requestId});
    })
    .onAfterHandle((ctx: Context) => {
      const { method, url } = ctx.request; 
      const { requestId, start } = ctx.store; //error
      let { status } = ctx.set;

      if(status && typeof(status) != 'number') {
        status = StatusMap[status];
      }

      const end = Date.now();
      const duration = end - start;

      logger.responseLog({method, url, status, duration, requestId})
    })
    .onError(({ code, error }) => {
      logger.error(error, `${error.message} ${code}`);
    });
};


I used resolve api to extend it
But dosen't work :
Property 'start' does not exist on type '{}'.
How can I fix it?
